# Передать объект File через интент

Tags: android, recyclerview

Галерея в recyclerview. Считываю в List список файлов из папки и показываю в списке. Задача по клику открыть фотку на новом экране. Обработка кликов в ViewHolder адаптера

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Onclick", "Onclick");
        Cursor cursor = null;
        String choosenPhotoPath;

        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            File file = photos.get(position);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            //получаем путь к фотке из URI
            try {
                String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Log.d("context", v.getContext().toString());
                cursor = v.getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                choosenPhotoPath = cursor.getString(column_index);
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DrawActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("choosenPhotoPath", choosenPhotoPath);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Принимающая активити

```
public class DrawActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_draw);

    String photoPath = getIntent().getStringExtra("choosenPhotoPath");

    ImageView editImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.edit_image);

    editImage.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(photoPath)));
}
```

}

По клику ловлю

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Не понимаю, почему курсор null

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не заставлять систему сериализовать весь объект `File`, вы можете передать в интенте только путь к файлу:

```
File file = photos.get(position);
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DrawActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("file_path", file.getAbsolutePath());
v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

И восстановить `File` из этого пути:

```
File file = new File(getIntent().getStringExtra("file_path", ""));
```

Comment: на самом деле этого я и хотел добиться! отлично!

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так.
File реализует serializable. Поэтому в адаптере:

```
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            File file = photos.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DrawActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("file", file);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
```

В принимающей активити

```
        File file = (File) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("file");

        ImageView editImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.edit_image);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(Uri.fromFile(file))
                .into(editImage);
```